# Why mysql Query Sending Data Slow

Tags: mysql, performance

my query

```
      SELECT Info.InfoID,
      SessionInfo.SessionInfoID,
      SessionInfo.ANI,
      ANumber.ANumber,
      tmfInfo.PTime,
      tmfInfo.PTry,
      SessionInfo.CardID,
      tmfInfo.Status
 FROM tmfInfo,
      SessionInfo,
      ANumber ,
      ANumberLog,
      ANumberGroup,
      ANumberGroupLog
WHERE (tmfInfo.IVRSessionInfoID = SessionInfo.IVRSessionInfoID)
  AND (SessionInfo.ANumberLogID = ANumber.ANumberLogID)
  AND (ANumber.AccessNumberLogID = ANumberLog.ANumberLogID)
  AND (ANumberrLog.ANumberGroupID = ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupID)
  AND (ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupLogID = ANumberGroupLog.ANumberGroupLogID)
  AND (SessionInfo.SessionCallTime >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00'
  AND (SessionInfo.SessionCallTime <= '2013-08-01 23:59:59')
  AND (ANumberLog.IsDeleted = '0')
  AND (ANumberLog.IsActive = '1')
  AND (ANumberGroupLog.IsDeleted = '0')
  AND (ANumberGroupLog.IsActive = '1')
 ORDER BY SessionInfo.SessionCallTime,tmfInfo.PTime DESC;
```

---

it results gives 1237 rows (10 sec)

when iam execute explain cmd

```
  id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
   1    SIMPLE  SessionInfo range   PRIMARY,SessionCallTime,ANumberLogID    SessionCallTime 4       57536   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
  1       SIMPLE    Anumber ref AnumberLogID    AnumberLogID    5               SessionInfo.ANumberLogID    1   Using where
  1     SIMPLE  AnumberLog  eq_ref  PRIMARY,ANumberGroupID,IsActive,IsDeleted   PRIMARY 4   SessionInfo.ANumberLogID    1   Using where
  1 SIMPLE  AnumberGroup    eq_ref  PRIMARY,ANumberGroupLogID   PRIMARY 4   AnumberLog.ANumberGroupID   1   
  1 SIMPLE  AnumberGroupLog eq_ref  PRIMARY,IsActive,IsDeleted  PRIMARY 4   AnumberGroup.ANumberGroupLogID  1   Using where
 1  SIMPLE  tmfInfo ref IVRSessionInfoID    IVRSessionInfoID    8   SessionInfo.IVRSessionInfoID    1
```

here query serching more than 57536  rows 
it will take more time to execute

sending data solw:__

```
                      Status    Duration
                     starting   0.000009
 Waiting for query cache lock   0.000003
  checking query cache for query    0.000087
          checking permissions  0.000003
         checking permissions   0.000002
         checking permissions   0.000002
         checking permissions   0.000002
         checking permissions   0.000002
         checking permissions   0.000003
                 Opening tables 0.000037
                 System lock    0.000007
 Waiting for query cache lock   0.000053
                        init    0.000039
                  optimizing    0.000018
                  statistics    0.000156
                          preparing 0.000033
           Creating tmp table   0.000029
                   executing    0.000002
          Copying to tmp table  0.353
              Sorting result    0.000238
                Sending data    7.763123
                          end   0.000009
            removing tmp table  0.000011
                           end  0.000004
                       query end    0.000004
                closing tables  0.000014
                freeing items   0.000018
            logging slow query  0.000003
          logging slow query    0.000025
                 cleaning up    0.000005
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on all of the columns you're joining on?

Comment: yes having..................

Comment: Yeah, saw that in the explain after I asked...

Comment: How many records in each table?  Do you really need all those joins?

Comment: 1728967,
 22041771,
 1200,
 2100,
 54,
 102.......

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38096/discussion-between-karukala-sr-and-steven-moseley)

Comment: What are the data types for ANumberLog.IsDeleted and SessionInfo.SessionCallTime

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

1. I put the Session info in a derived table subquery to try to limit the number of rows you're joining on tmfInfo.
2. EDIT: I'm casting the date range to UNIX_TIMESTAMP to improve performance on your timestamp field.  THIS IS A BIG ONE!!!!

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    ssnInfo.*
    tmfInfo.PTime,
    tmfInfo.PTry,
    tmfInfo.Status

FROM (
    SELECT
        Info.InfoID,
        SessionInfo.SessionInfoID,
        SessionInfo.ANI,
        ANumber.ANumber,
        SessionInfo.CardID
    FROM
        SessionInfo
        INNER JOIN ANumber AS
            ON ANumber.ANumberLogID = SessionInfo.ANumberLogID,
        INNER JOIN ANumberLog
            ON ANumberLog.ANumberLogID = ANumber.AccessNumberLogID
            AND ANumberLog.IsDeleted = 0 /* Do not put this in quotes unless it's stored as a string */
            AND ANumberLog.IsActive = 1 /* Do not put this in quotes unless it's stored as a string */
        INNER JOIN ANumberGroup
            ON ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupID = ANumberLog.ANumberGroupID
        INNER JOIN ANumberGroupLog
            ON ANumberGroupLog.ANumberGroupLogID = ANumberGroup.ANumberGroupLogID
            AND ANumberGroupLog.IsDeleted = 0 /* Do not put this in quotes unless it's stored as a string */
            AND ANumberGroupLog.IsActive = 1 /* Do not put this in quotes unless it's stored as a string */
    WHERE 
        SessionInfo.SessionCallTime 
            BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01 00:00:00') 
            AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-15 23:59:59')
    ) AS ssnInfo
INNER JOIN tmfInfo
    ON ssnInfo.IVRSessionInfoID = tmfInfo.IVRSessionInfoID
```

Comment: thanks sir, but iam not getting results with this.. i need ordery by also ORDER BY SessionInfo.SessionCallTime,tmfInfo.PTime DESC;

Comment: /* Do not put this in quotes unless it's stored as a string */ this is wrong                                                                        when iam using quotes  '0', i got results

Comment: and its taking same time

Comment: What are the data types for ANumberLog.IsDeleted and SessionInfo.SessionCallTime

Comment: enum('0','1') & timestamp

Comment: Please read [this link](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/). You just did the most evil of the 8 evil things about enum...

Comment: Edited this to add a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` call on your timestamp field.  This should boost your performance quite a bit.

Comment: SELECT SessionInfo.IVRSessionInfoID
FROM   SessionInfo
WHERE  SessionCallTime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01 00:00:00') 
                           AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01 23:59:59')
ORDER  BY SessionInfo.SessionCallTime DESC;                                      when iam execute this query it shows 0 rows here'